# SignalR disconnects and does not reconnect

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

Whenever my application gets reset, signalR disconnects but does not reconnect.

I have a long running server task which sends updates to clients when each task is completed.

```
// inside action executed on every completion of a task
var h = new ForceHub();
h.MessageSent(email);
```

above code stops sending updates when application gets reset (i can emulate this problem by touching web.config).

I'd like a way to reconnect to a client. Currently the user has to reload the page for it to get updates again.

Here is my hub definition

```
public class ForceHub : Hub
{
    public void MessageSent(string text)
    {
        GetContext().Clients.All.sent(text);
    }

    public void UpdateStatus(string msg)
    {
        GetContext().Clients.All.status(msg);
    }

    IHubContext GetContext()
    {
        return GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ForceHub>();
    }
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        try {
            IoC.Resolve<ILogger>().Info("SignalR Connected -----------");
        }catch (Exception){}

        return base.OnConnected();
    }

    public override Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        try {
            IoC.Resolve<ILogger>().Info("SignalR Disconnected -----------");
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }

    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        try {
            IoC.Resolve<ILogger>().Info("SignalR Re-Connected -----------");
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        return base.OnReconnected();
    }
}
```

I can see *Connected* and *Re-Connected* events triggered after startup, however after touching web.config, I don't see any of these events triggered.

i tried catching this on the client, but this event is not tirggered:

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
    console.error('signalR disconnected, retrying connection');
    logError('Signal lost.');
    setTimeout(function () { connection.start(); }, 1000);
});
```

**update**

I also hooked into State Changed event, which does get triggered, but the re-connection attempt below does not work.

```
        $.connection.hub.stateChanged(function (state) {
            console.debug('signalR state changed', state);
            if (state.newState == 1) {
                console.debug('restarting');
                setTimeout(function () { $.connection.hub.start(); }, 1000);
            }
        });
```

this event gets triggered twice: newState is 2 ,and then 1.

Comment: It looked like an interesting case, and I tried to repro it, but I was not able to. I did not try with long running tasks, but with a simple additional page whose code behind sends a message to all clients when hit with a GET. This simulates an "out of band" job, and it works normally even after an application reset, clients get notified normally. I'd say SignalR does not loose the connection (that's why you do not see the events)... Maybe the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: @Wasp did you try modifying web.config ?

Comment: Sure, I was doing that between requests to my "job" page

Comment: ok thanks for trying. I'll post some more debugging code now. Maybe that will make more sense to you

Comment: FYI, I added your further event handler I see the state change events happening, and still the connection is not lost after a change in web config, my "job" page when loaded is still able to notify all connected clients after that. This is consistent with what SignalR is supposed to do (being at "reconnecting" does not mean a "disconnected" happened).

Comment: Ok, what may be unique for me is that I am using a web api. I've tested this, and a web api method does not terminate after touching web.config. The tasks that was started continues, but it is in some weird disconnected state.. meaning some things do reset.. But things like logging still work from my task, just the signalR does not. Also the server connection events do not get triggered :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have a clue... Touching the Web.config produces an appPool Recycle, meaning that a new worker process will be created for new requests while the existing process will continue for a while until the remaining requests end or the timeout is reached. Request that do not end in the timeout period are terminated.

Signalr client reconnects to the new process while the long running task is running in the old process, so when on the long running task you do

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ForceHub>();
```

you actually get a reference for "old" hub while the client is connected to the "new" hub.
That's why the test preformed by Wasp worked: he was making a new request to publish on the signalr hub that was processed in the newly created worker process.

You could try to configure a singalr backplane (https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr), it’s really easy to configure it using Sql Server (https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-sql-server). The backplane should be capable of connect the two worker processes and hopefully you will get the notification on the client.

If this is the problem, notifications generated by new requests will work even without the backplane. Notice that the real purpose of the backplane is to scale out signalr, this is, to connect a farm of WebServers between them.

Also keep in mind that running long-running task inside IIS is as task hard to achieve as, among other things, IIS does regular appPool recycles and has timeout limits for the requests to execute. I recommend that you read the following post: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx 
“If you think you can just write a background task yourself, it's likely you'll get it wrong. I'm not impugning your skills, I'm just saying it's subtle. Plus, why should you have to?”

Hope this helps

Comment: that sounds about right :) have not touched that code in years. I agree that long running tasks in IIS are not ideal. i was able to bring the execution span down to 1-30min which is still long but has been manageable for the past few years. thanks!