# SignalR Clients.Client($id) Invalid

Tags: c#, signalr

I am trying to call methods server-side from:

```
var client = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<HUB>().Clients.Client(ConnectionID);
```

where `ConnectionID` is coming straight from the client `$.connection.hub.id`. However, after about 30ish seconds, executing client commands with this object fails silently. It's as if it's talking to a client that doesn't exist.
Additionally, I have tried

```
var client = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<HUB>().Clients.User(User.Identity.Name);
```

but similarly, this also starts returning null after about a minute.

Is there some kind of cache that is being cleared after a time?
I am listening to OnConnect and OnDisconnect both on the server and client and none are fired.

EDIT: I realized that the Clients.Client() method is not returning null, but just an invalid object.

EDIT 2: I am looking into the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23727309/signalr-disconnects-and-does-not-reconnect?rq=1) because it involves load balanced servers (my situation)

Comment: Been a while since I used SignalR but isn't `$.connection.hub.id` for client-side?  See [How to obtain connection ID of signalR client on the server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908620/how-to-obtain-connection-id-of-signalr-client-on-the-server-side)

Comment: I also use `Context.ConnectionId` server-side, but the reason I specified `$.connection.hub.id` is because the client does **not** change it's id while the server `GlobalHost` no longer recognizes it.